# sort and join file in bash (script)

Tags: bash, sorting, join

How do I get each field of the join command output to be separated by tabs?

Comment: `X || Y` means `do Y only if X fails`. Surely that's not what you want?

Comment: If you want to sort a file, `x`, in place, use `sort -o x x`; this is safe and does not clobber the input file until the sorted data is being written.  You might then use `sort -o annotation.txt annotation.txt; sort -o output2.txt output2.txt; join output2.txt annotation.txt > outputtest.txt`.  If you think there will be error messages and you really want them in the output file, then use `&>` instead of just `>`. If you don't want to reorder the files permanently, use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) as suggested by Charles Duffy.

Comment: nop haha I mean do X and Y and then use them both for Z

Comment: In file1, are there tabs for blank fields after a `no hit`, or is that just end-of-line? If you've got blank fields, output should be exactly what you want (after using `-t $'\t'` as previously suggested).

Comment: no it's end-of-line

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for a process substitution:

```
join <(sort annotation) <(sort output2.txt) >outputtest.txt
```

In this usage, `<(sort annotation)` will be replaced with a file-like object (either `/dev/fd/10`-form or a named pipe) which, when read from, contains the output of the command `sort annotation`. Thus, `join` will see sorted input without needing to modify either file in-place (which the original code didn't actually do).

Comment: thanks that works! although I have a question, does it merge the first column if it's the same in both files? also, is there anyway to tell him to display the output using tabs, or should I use an other command afterwards?

Comment: I'd want to know more about the input format and use case. You can use `-t $'\t'` as an argument to `join` to specify tabs be used for both input and output. If you want to specify the first column as the merge field, `-j 1` makes that explicit.

Comment: alright I'll edit my post! but about the merging thing, I don't especially want to merge the first columns of the file, but when I tried the command line you gave me, it did merge the first columns (which btw are the same in both files)

Comment: It'll definitely do some good to know what you *want* your output to look like (and to have sample input), in terms of enabling a answer that describes how to get there.

Comment: It looks like you didn't follow my suggestion of using `-t $'\t'` above.

Comment: I did but still it doesn't align the last field

Comment: Right -- to get it to align that field, you need enough tabs on the end of your first file to make it line up. Frankly, how best to do that should probably be a separate question of its own -- editing your question *into a completely different question* after it's correctly answered is not exactly kosher.