# Bash, join 2 files based on ids/columns, different positions, not sorted, some ids are missing in one file

Tags: bash, file, join

**Need**

Join 2 files based on same ids, but columns are on different positions, not sorted, and some ids are missing in one of these files. Generate to `file3.csv`.

**Source files**

File `file1.csv`, example.

```
...

4,238324
4,217814
5,222456
4,238323

...
```

File `file2.csv`, example.

```
...

"225929",Stříška komínová 118 mm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/225929.jpg,189.00,189.00
"222456",Lopatka na uhlí Mars - pozinkovaná,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/210769.jpg,49.00,49.00
"229456",Deska Grenamat 600 x 800 x 20 mm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/229456.jpg,499.00,499.00
"238324",Deska šamotová 250 x 120 x 20 mm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/229783.jpg,35.00,35.00
"114307",Konvektor FK330,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/114307-1.jpg,599.00,599.00

...
```

**Expected results**

File `file3.csv`, example.

```
4,"238324",Deska šamotová 250 x 120 x 20 mm,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/229783.jpg,35.00,35.00
5,"222456",Lopatka na uhlí Mars - pozinkovaná,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/210769.jpg,49.00,49.00

... etc.
```

Some rows/ids are missing in `file2.csv`, so in this case add only row from `file1.csv`.

**Tried**

```
join -t',' -j 1 file2.csv -j 2 file1.csv
join: incompatible join fields 1, 2
(same situation in case without " in column 1 in file2.csv)

awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=substr($0,length($1)+2);next} ($1 in a){print $0","a[$1]}' file1.csv file2.csv
(empty)
```

Do I have to use `if` conditions via bash script, or is there a simplest way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a process substitution to feed the output of `sort` direct into `join`. That is: `join -t, -j 1 <(sort -k1,1 <file2.csv) <(sort -k2,2 <file1.csv)` or something of that variety, such that `join` reads a stream that `sort` has already ordered by the key at hand.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680512/sort-and-join-file-in-bash-script discussing using process substitution when combining sort and join; and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29375621/14122 re: `sort -k`.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the original order of lines from file1.csv?

Comment: The quotes in the join field in the second file do make using `join` a bit problematic. Hmm.

Comment: `man join` and read about -e` (empty) option. Good luck.

Comment: Can any of the other fields be quoted (because of  embedded commas in particular)?

Comment: @hek2mgl Exactly, I need order of lines from file1.csv.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, of course. In case of problem with quotes in file2.csv, I can export this column without quotes.

Comment: Hello, I tried `join -t, -12 -21 <(sort -h -t, -k2 <file1.csv) <(sort -h -t, -k1 <file2.csv)`, but it join only few rows. I've got some error for one row, `join: /dev/fd/62:68: is not sorted: ...`. What is wrong? Thanks.